# FUNCTION INDEX + MATCH alternate solution

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I hope you can help me with the following query. I am performing a search in the matrix located in the range A2: G481 to bring me the values corresponding to the columns F and G, according to the criteria of Age (B: B), Year ($ I $ 2) and Percentage according to gender (Male [F: F] and Female [G: G]). In columns L, M and N I have already performed a calculation like the one I am looking for, applying the SUMIFS function and it has given results. Now I want to replicate the same calculation but this time using the INDEX and MATCH function, for which I have done it in columns Q, R and S. For the male percentage [column R], the calculations return the expected result, but when I try to apply the same function this time for the female percentage [O], I get #REF!

I clarify that the cell I2 corresponds to a drop-down list containing the years from 1996 to 2019, this with the intention that when the year is selected, the results return the numbers corresponding to that date.

I hope you can tell me where I am making the mistake or if I can apply a simpler procedure using INDEX and MATCH.

Thank you for your attention.

[workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1flo6wWUBOOoCiMz-JMDv3IVr_BID1-wI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Post the formulas that throw the error. `#REF!` means that a reference cannot be resolved, for example `=index(A1:A10,20)` So you need to work out what the components of the formula return. Also, nobody wants to snorkel through your google sheet. Post a data sample HERE to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: @teylyn I can't explain it more clearly with words, that's why the intention of uploading the spreadsheet to understand the problems presented by the formula. You want to know what the problem is without first understanding how the formula has been proposed, explaining it in words would be difficult to understand, I can attach the formula but it would give the same result without seeing what you are looking for with it. [=INDEX($F2:$G481;MATCH($I$2;$A$2:$A$481;0);MATCH($Q2;$B2:$B481;0);MATCH(S$1;$F$1:$G$1;0))]

Comment: Simplify. We don't need all your data. And I can already tell you three problems about the index/match formula you posted without seeing any data: It has too many arguments (unless you really want to work with area_num, which I doubt), the argument that returns the column number is responsible for the #REF! error, because it can return a number larger than the columns in the index, and you haven't really understood the architecture of index/match. Therefore, start with a small data sample and explain the logic of the lookup you want to perform.

Comment: They already solved my doubt thanks to the fact that they understood the procedure where I was having problems and the worksheet I attached where the calculations and formulas were recorded.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell R2 =INDEX($F2:$F481,MATCH($I$2,$A$2:$A$481,0),MATCH($Q2,$B2:$B481,0),MATCH(R$1,$F1:$G1,0))
```

Your last match is fooling up.  Eliminate it.

```
Cell R2 =INDEX($F2:$F481,MATCH($I$2,$A$2:$A$481,0),MATCH($Q2,$B2:$B481,0))

Cell S2 =INDEX($G2:$G481,MATCH($I$2,$A$2:$A$481,0),MATCH($Q2,$B2:$B481,0))
```

Limit range to males and females.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had already considered that option, but I really want it to perform the search considering columns F and G at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of a user, he was able to guide me to find a solution to the problem that I had been registering, he kindly helped me with the explanation and found the following expression that solves the problem using INDEX + MATCH

```
Col R =INDEX($F$2:$G$481,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$481=$I$2)*($B$2:$B$481=$Q2),0),0),MATCH(R$1,$F$1:$G$1,0))

Col S =INDEX($F$2:$G$481,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$481=$I$2)*($B$2:$B$481=$Q2),0),0),MATCH(S$1,$F$1:$G$1,0))
```